# Cant force two html objects in one line

Tags: html, css

Here is what I tried:

```
<li>
    <label>Some label</label>
    <i class="fa fa-crosshairs fa-2x" style="float: left; color: #009530; margin: 3px 5px 0 0"></i><input type="text" size="16" placeholder="Some placeholder">
    <span class="tooltipPG zipcode"><img src="common/css/img/tooltip.png">Some tooltip</span>
</li>
```

I need font awsome icon to be on the right of the text box which needs to take 100% of the remaining space.

Here is the css of the text field that it uses:

```
.map-heading .search-criteria > ul.normal-fields > li:nth-child(1) input {
    width:  100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: You have, `width:  100%;` so there isn't any remaining space.

Comment: Then I change this to 80% and it does not fit in the remaining space leaving some free space after the text box. How to make both (fit 100% and one line)?

Comment: shouldn't be float:right..?